# How to pass name value to controller in SAP UI5?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

**XML**

```
table.bindItems({
                path: "/",
                template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [
                        new sap.m.Text({
                            text: "{account_name}"
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "Disconnect",
                            name:"{account_id}",
                            press: [that.handleButtonPress, this]
                        })
                    ]
                })
            });
```

**JS**

```
handleButtonPress: function (oEvent) {
}
```

Here I dynamicaly bind a json data to a table. I put one button there. When I click on button, I need to take that name value in controller. How to do this..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the the context passed to button press handler to `that` instead to `this` where that is referring to your controller. i.e

```
table.bindItems({
            path: "/",
            template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                cells: [
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "{account_name}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Button({
                        text: "Disconnect",
                        name:"{account_id}",
                        press: [that.handleButtonPress, that]
                    })
                ]
            })
        });
```

and in your controller:

```
handleButtonPress: function (oEvent) {
     console.log(this); // this is your controller.
     var source = oEvent.getSource();
     console.log(source) // this is your button.
     var oBindingObject = source.getBindingContext().getObject();
     console.log(oBindingObject.account_id);// will print the button text
```

}